# How to update only 3 column value in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page model. It has following columns in database table:

- id
- name
- email
- password
- status
- privilege
- usr_prf_color
- usr_prf_nav
- usr_prf_scroll

I want to update only 3 column value which are usr_prf_color, usr_prf_nav and usr_prf_scroll.

Here's my controller code:

```
  public function themeUpdate(UpdateThemeRequest $request , User $user)
{
      $user->update($request->all());
      
      $request->usr_prf_color;
      $request->usr_prf_nav;
      $request->usr_prf_scroll;

      $this->validate($request, [

        'usr_prf_color' =>['required'],
        'usr_prf_nav' => ['required'],
        'usr_prf_scroll' => ['required'],

      ]);

    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    $data = $request-> only(['usr_prf_color','usr_prf_nav','usr_prf_scroll']);
 
    $user->update($data);

    $theme = DB::table('users')
                ->select('usr_prf_color','usr_prf_nav','usr_prf_scroll')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->get();

               
    return view('profile.index',compact('theme'));

}
```

Here's my view code:

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.themeUpdate', auth()->user()->id) }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf 
                                        @method('PUT')
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Color</label>
                                                <select name="usr_prf_color" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="light">Light</option>
                                                    <option value="dark">Dark</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Navigation</label>
                                                <select name="usr_prf_nav" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="horizontal">Horizontal</option>
                                                    <option value="vertical">Vertical</option>
                                                    <option value="hidden">Hidden</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Scroll</label>
                                                <select name="usr_prf_scroll" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="scrollable">Scrollable</option>
                                                    <option value="non-scrollable">Non-Scrollable</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                </form>
```

Here's my route:

```
Route::put('profile-theme', 'UserProfileController@themeUpdate')->name('profile.themeUpdate');
```

Here's my model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

{
use Notifiable;

```
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'status', 'privilege' ,'password', 'usr_prf_color', 'usr_prf_nav', 'usr_prf_scroll',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

There's no error when I run this coding, but the data does not stored into database. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Check `$fillable` attribute in User. It should be an array with fields which could be mass assigned (i.e. via `update()` method).

Comment: @Daniel is correct maybe you didn't add your columns to the $fillable in models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view add id in an input hidden,
in your controller add

```
User::where('id', $request->input('id'))->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try following code:It should work.
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'usr_prf_color' =>'required',
    'usr_prf_nav' => 'required',
    'usr_prf_scroll' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  return redirect('profile.index')
           ->withErrors($validator)
           ->withInput();
}
 
$user = User::where('id', $request->input('id');
$user->update($request->only(['usr_prf_color','usr_prf_nav','usr_prf_scroll']));

$theme = $user->refresh();
           
return view('profile.index',compact('theme'));
```